# Catalog Search is not working

Tags: search, catalogsearch, advanced-search

There are several products of different brands in my Site of Magento 1.8.1.0. If I try to find out products of **savina** using URL **beautycare.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=savina** I am getting products of **savina**. But if I try to find out products of **ibd** using URL **beautycare.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=ibd** I am getting a blank page without any product with message **Your search returns no results.**

Why it is happening ? How can I solve the issue.

Comment: Did u tried reindexing?

Comment: @PrasantaHatui Yes, I tried reindexing.

Comment: What is the configuration you are using in **Sytem->configuration->catalog->catalogsearch** ?

Answer (score 0):

All "searchable" attributes must be configured in **Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes**. You'll notice column **"Searchable"**. All attributes with value **"Yes"** will be considered during search process.

So, question is, is your word "ibd" part of any searchable attribute? If it's part of a product name, for example, "IBD connector", then it should be fixed by reindexing. But, if it's part of attribute "custom_attribute" which is not set as "searchable," then you cannot find such product. In that case, you have to set "custom_attribute" as searchable and perform catalog search reindex.

Also, try to reindex from command line by calling:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```